# Determine length of each line in multiline Text

Tags: swift, text, swiftui, geometryreader

I write a solution to replace text with some kind of placeholder for updating data.

For example from such:

[image]

I have to get such:

[image]

But currently with solution:

```
public struct ShimmerText: View {

private var text: String
@Binding private var loading: Bool
@State private var frame = CGRect.zero
private var accessibilityIdentifier: String

public init(text: String,
            loading: Binding<Bool>,
            accessibilityIdentifier: String) {
    self.text = text
    self._loading = loading
    self.accessibilityIdentifier = accessibilityIdentifier
}

public var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if loading {
            Text(text)
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .background(rectReader($frame))
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

            VStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .frame(maxWidth: frame.width)
                    .frame(height: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(.colorDivider)

                if frame.height > 24 {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .frame(width: frame.width, height: 16)
                        .foregroundColor(.colorDivider)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text(text)
                .accessibility(identifier: accessibilityIdentifier)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
}

func rectReader(_ binding: Binding<CGRect>) -> some View {
    return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
        let rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            binding.wrappedValue = rect
        }
        return .clear
    }
}
```

I can get only:

[image]

You can see, that last two placeholder's lines has length of maximal line, but it should repeat length of each line. Also text could be longer than 3 lines.

I think I need to find length of each line of text in multiline Text.

Comment: If it's a placeholder, doesn't that mean you can't know how long the text is? And therefore  how large to make the placeholder? I know it's not a solution, but I think this is not an issue.

Comment: @vrwim Yes, it is a placeholder, but in general all text will not change, just some numbers inside so +- length of lines will be the same